# How to declare variables from a text file in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I would like to load string from a text file as a variable. For example a insecure login screen which the user enters their credentials into a textbox which the program will read what has been entered into the textbox and will load the next form when the credentials are the same stored in the text file.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Have a look at the [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) first to see what kind of question you can ask here and what you should include.

Comment: Please post your answer in the *answer box*, rather than as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:Solved it over 1 and half hours of googling

```
Public Class Form1
    Public pass As String = String.Empty
    Public user As String = String.Empty
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox2.Text = (user) And TextBox1.Text = (pass) Then
            Login.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password or User Name")
        End If
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        If TextBox2.Text = "" And TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pass = IO.File.ReadAllText("pass.txt")
    user = IO.File.ReadAllText("user.txt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

just used IO.File.ReadAllText("user.txt") Which will read all the string in the text file and store them into the empty variable not the best method but works for this application